Horror movie about violent plants
I have seen this american horror movie almost 5 or 6 years ago, my guess is that it is released after 2002. I remember watching it on osn so it must be very well produced.
I clearly remember that they was many young couples (possibly three) going on a normal trip together somewhere (typical start of horror movies where everything looks fine until something happens).
There is a scene where a girl was standing on top of a hill, and green plants start coming through her, and climbing.
If the plants gets on one's feet, it would start eating it. I think a guy's feet hit accidentally the plant and his feet was all blood (if not amputated). 
I don't remember anything else except perhaps that not everyone survives, and they die one by one.
It is stuck in my memory because it has violent scenes and gore. Its rating would be for sure strictly for adults.

The Ruins (2008)?   
quick summary:

A group of friends whose leisurely Mexican holiday takes a turn for
  the worse when they, along with a fellow tourist embark on a remote
  archaeological dig in the jungle, where something evil lives among the
  ruins.

If the plants gets on one's feet, it would start eating it. I think a guy's feet hit accidentally the plant and his feet was all blood (if not amputated). 

Stacy observes a tendril of vine has crept into a wound on her leg
  during the night. The vines have also wrapped themselves around
  Mathias's lower legs and eaten them down to the bone. Eric and Jeff
  are barely able to remove the vines from Stacy but cannot get them off
  of Mathias.

Trailer:



